# Laravel: No error message is shown on form submission

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Route definition:

```
Route::get('/sign_up','NavigationController@show_sign_up');
Route::post('/sign_up','DatainsertController@sign_up_data');
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\sender;

class DatainsertController extends Controller
{
    public function sign_up_data(Request $request)
    {  

        //create a new post using the request data 
        $post=new post;
        $post->first_name=$request('first_name');
        $post->last_name=$request('last_name');

        //save to the database 

        $post->save();

        //the redirect to the home page 

        return redirect('/');

    }
}
```

This is the error message I see:
[image: this is the error message]

I use the post method on my route, and a CSRF token in the form, but the data is never sent to the database although everything seems correct.

Comment: post your form too

Comment: `$request('first_name');` is wrong, should be `$request->input('first_name');` or something.

Comment: try clearing your cache **php artisan route:clear**  This error might occur if your route is wrong in form so check your route too

Comment: you should use $request['first_name']; instead $request('first_name');

Comment: The error occurs on `/login`, not your route - have you been redirected there because your Save-Controller/Route requires a login?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\sender;
use App\Post;

class DatainsertController extends Controller
{
    public function sign_up_data(Request $request)
    {  

        //create a new post using the request data 
        $post=new Post;
        $post->first_name=$request->first_name;
        $post->last_name=$request->last_name;

        //save to the database 

        $post->save();

        //the redirect to the home page 

        return redirect('/');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Post Your Form code here maybe you're not set action in form. check your form action it must like this.

```
<form action="{{url('/sign_up')}}" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

Method Not Allowed Exception will occur with route method configuration issue.

**First check your routes, (web.php)**

```
Route::get('/sign_up','NavigationController@show_sign_up')->name('getsignup');

Route::post('/sign_up','DatainsertController@sign_up_data')->name('postsignup');
```

**Go to your  view ,**

open dev tools and see if your browser is actually doing a POST not a GET

> also try changing action="/fproject/public/sign_up" to action="{{
>   route('postsignup') }}"

**Go to controller**

```
Add namespace like `App\Post` or whatever required.
```

There is no other solution.